# Oracle AQ: History Table

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-aq

Is there a simple way in oracle to create a History table of a queue table? The payload type of the queue table is specific type, so if i want to create a normal history table would this specific payload type be a problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are still on 10g, [dbms_wm](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14253/long_ref.htm#ADWSM020) is one option you might want to take a look at. You can version enable a table and all further DML against the table will be converted so that history is maintained.

You can take a look at the implementation here. 
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/WorkspaceManagement9i.php#VersionEnablingATable

Please note that this will impact performance since you have triggers firing on different DML to implement versioning.

About the payload type comment, I don't know of any specific constraints with types. You can probably try a small table with your user-defined type and see if you have any issues.

Comment: i have to avoid any thing that will impact performance, this is why i didn't use the retention time of the queue, which was tested and made performance issues. I don't know if triggers on a queue table has also impact on performance i have to check that before using a separate history table.